# Why does the String show length 1?

Tags: powershell

In the following code, I am reading value from an Excel, match it with another string and want to read the length of the variable. However it always shows the value **1**...
Can somebody explain me why?

BR

```
$FilePath = "randompath"

$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)
$Worksheet = $Workbook.Sheets.Item(1)

$zahl1 = $worksheet.Cells.Item(1, 1).Value2

$docpath | out-string


[string]$Test = $docpath
$Cut = 13

If($Test -match("LBIW")){
$postiitonLBIW=$Test.IndexOf("LBIW")
$result1=$Test.Substring($postiitonLBIW)
$result1=$Test.Split("\")
$zahl1 = $result1 -match "LBIW" 
$zahl1 = $zahl1.length
write-host $zahl1
```

Comment: Nowhere in the code you've provided is the `Length` property referenced - which variable are we talking about? :)

Comment: you are right. I now added it

Answer (score 3):

The issue is `$zahl1` is set to `$true` or `$false`, which is a length of 1.

```
$zahl1 = $result1 -match "LBIW" 
$zahl1 = $zahl1.length
```

If you want the matches, you have to use `$matches[n]`.  The way you are assigning `$zahl1` is the output whether a match was found or not.

The better way:

```
$zahl1Len = 0 #default var incase no matches
if ($result1 -match "LBIW") { # if it has a match, process
    $zahl1 = $matches[1] # or whatever match index
    $zahl1Len = $zahl1.length
}
```

This way it is assigned the first match and counts the length, if it was matched.